# Stuck with eslint Error i.e Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have the Code for some iterations and it works well. After installing eslint, One of my code generates an error by eslint.

My code is:

```
for (const column of columns) {
    for (const slugname of result[column.name]) {
        const alphabet = slugname.slugname;
        if (total[alphabet]) {
            total[alphabet] += column.value;
        } else {
            total[alphabet] = column.value;
        }
    }
}
```

eslint generates an error which is this

`error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax`

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated for that. According to me The code was written very precisely and very small, don't know about the clue of eslint error

Comment: Have you try not to use `for ... of`?

Comment: no because for will handle much better than foreach

Comment: would array.find() solve the issue? [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Consider using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: Consider using the ```.map()``` function, unless in the case where you want to iterate through an async block in **series**, in which case you should set up an ignore for this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
columns.map(x => result[x.name].map((y) => {
  const alphabet = y.slugname;
  if (total[alphabet]) {
      total[alphabet] += x.value;
    } else {
      total[alphabet] = x.value;
    }
    return true;
}));
```

Comment: Why does this answer have upvotes? It's got no explanation at all. Additionally the code is not as readable as the initial posters.

Answer (score 14):

There is nothing wrong with your code, this is outdated guidance.

"iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime" hasn't been true since 2014 caniuse.com/es6-generators this error looks like it came from airbnb's style guide and you'd have to ask them if they still stick to it

Comment: Can you cite why this guidance is outdated? I believe you're correct, but a more through explanation would benefit everybody reading this.

Comment: "iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime" hasn't been true since 2014 https://caniuse.com/es6-generators this error looks like it came from airbnb's style guide and you'd have to ask them if they still stick to it.